# sleeping of one proces in between in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have make an menu in which first option is to start and second is to stop the services and third i want to develop is of restart in which services
will be stop first and then a 20 seconds break will be theres and then the services will be started again now please advise for restart option that I have code is correct or not..
I want an stopdown watch also to be dispayed which will show the reverse counting like 1,then 2 then 3 and then on 20 it will say starting the services

```
echo "Please enter the appropriate choice for doing the operations"
    echo "
    1) STOP Services        
    2) START Services 
    3  RestartServices Within 20 seconds
case $choice in
    1)
        echo "*************Stopping Services**************"
        stopAll.sh
        ;;
    2)
        echo "*************Starting Services**************"
        startAll.sh
        ;;
    3)
        echo "*************Restarting services within 20 Seconds*************"
        stopAll.sh
        sleep 20 seconds  //please avise is this this correct way  to sleep the services for 20 seconnds..??////
        startAll.sh

        ;;
```

Comment: i think it shldbe 'sleep 20s'

Comment: You are not even bothering of searching your doubts on google, you are just firing the doubts on this site : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941842/script-not-reading-3-and-4-option, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941409/getting-error-in-the-below-script and another question has been deleted by you. Moreover you are not accepting any answers. I think you should try solving the problem or searching for the solution yourself before asking it here.

Answer (score 1):

From the sleep manpage:

> NAME
>
> ```
>   sleep - delay for a specified amount of time
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX]...
>   sleep OPTION
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   Pause for NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default),
>   'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.  Unlike most  implemen‐
>   tations  that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbi‐
>   trary floating point number.  Given two or more  arguments,  pause  for
>   the amount of time specified by the sum of their values.
> ```

You will want to use `sleep 20s` but `s` is the default so `sleep 20` should work.